# AWS WafV2 OR Statement / IPSetReference

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-waf, amazon-acl

I am trying to understand this awesome documentation:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-wafv2-webacl-orstatementone.html

Which tells me to just write it this way:

```
Statements: 
    - StatementTwo
```

**What I want to do:**
I want to make sure that the IP is in either one of two - three different IPSet's I have created. I want to avoid creating multiple rules, since from what I understand, every rule costs 1$ each month. The only reason I want to have multiple IP sets is to make it clear why each IP was added to each set. (Homeoffice, Regular office, Consultant etc).

I have tried *some* variations of this:

```
 Rules:
        - Name: WafIpRule
          Priority: 1
          Action:
            Allow: {}
          VisibilityConfig:
            SampledRequestsEnabled: false
            CloudWatchMetricsEnabled: true
            MetricName: !Sub web${Environment}AllowWhitelistedIps
          Statement:
            Statements:
              - IPSetReferenceStatement:
                  Arn: !GetAtt IpStuff1.Arn
              - IPSetReferenceStatement:
                  Arn: !GetAtt IpStuff2.Arn
```

Is this even possible? If yes how? Or should I just go and merge the IpSets / Do seperate rules?

I seem to be able to do this via the console so it seems like it should be possible...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit embarrassing since this was so close to what I was trying but a little bit of rubber ducking goes a long way.

I am not sure if AWS actually counts this as 2 (or more) rules but they do count the WCU's used (so I assume it will).

```
  Statement:
    OrStatement:
      Statements:
        - IPSetReferenceStatement:
            Arn: !GetAtt IpList1.Arn
        - IPSetReferenceStatement:
            Arn: !GetAtt IpList2.Arn
```

I will leave this here for future Google-fu's

Comment: You have any idea how its write in c# im getting this error https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/10058 please have a look